# overlapping UINavbar left item

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

On my swift iOS 8 project, i changed the back button image into a back arrow and removed the back item text using the following code in AppDelegate, but still getting an overlapping item.

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "GoBack")!
 let backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "GoBack")!
 UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImg, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

How do i remove the text?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more line:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

One more way to set image for bar button by using custom button this way:

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "GoBack"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "backButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 31)  // set this as per your need.

let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Helper method for it:

```
func backButtonPressed(sender:UIButton) {
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: Still, the image appears too big.https://www.dropbox.com/s/64js0jflfpxvpsf/Screenshot%202015-09-18%2002.29.24.png?dl=0

Comment: You can change image size.